# Windows Subsystem for Linux Error: 0x800703fa Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After a Windows 10 update, I'm getting this error while starting WSL Ubuntu 18.

I have tried to restart a couple of times, but the error is still there

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x800703fa
Error: 0x800703fa Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion.

Press any key to continue...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution has been provided by Github's user [@friedwm](https://github.com/friedwm) on this issue comment:

https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2576#issuecomment-380823857

The solution is to restart `LxssManager` from `services.msc`, or start it if it is not running.

Answer (score 0):

**Settings > Apps&Features > *select* Ubuntu > Advanced options > Repair**